# How much does SE care about mirrors of SE that don't acknowledge the CC licence?

Tags: support

I found this (replace the XXX's) as the #1 hit for a question.  The answer seemed very "stack exchange" and indeed it was:

http://htmlasks_XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/why_is_the_ubuntu_software_center_being_replaced_by_gnome_software_in_16_04

[Why is the Ubuntu Software Center being replaced by GNOME Software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725975/why-is-the-ubuntu-software-center-being-replaced-by-gnome-software)

Does SE patrol for such things: is there a reporting mechanism?

Comment: There's a [meta.se] post about this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do

Comment: Pretty much, if there aren't clear links back to SE, names aren't linked to corresponding users, or there's a nofollow tag in links, report the site. Scrapers are fine, but only if they follow the guidelines.